# How to make dio retry on flutter 2.0

Tags: flutter, dio

I'm using `dio_retry ^0.1.9-beta` it work on `flutter v1.22.4` but `flutter v2.0.0`

When the library is not yet supported, I want to do it manual.

Has anyone done this yet?

I need everyone's advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download library to local and migrate manual at https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide

Then add library migrated to project as library local.